# Free Cell dichotomy

Tags: solitaire, free-cell

Is it possible to solve the free cell game 
3267279 
I would appreciate it if anyone can let me know if it is possible as it  is driving me nuts 
MC

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. You can enter the game number into [this online solver](https://fc-solve.shlomifish.org/js-fc-solve/text/), and it will show you the full solution.

Here are the first several moves:

```
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

Foundations: H-0 C-0 D-0 S-0
Freecells:
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC 3C 4C
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D AC 3S
: 5H 8C 8S 5D AD TS 6C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 4H
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 2D 5S JC AH JD 5C
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move a card from stack 7 to freecell 1

Foundations: H-0 C-0 D-0 S-0
Freecells:  5C
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC 3C 4C
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D AC 3S
: 5H 8C 8S 5D AD TS 6C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 4H
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 2D 5S JC AH JD
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move a card from stack 7 to freecell 2

Foundations: H-0 C-0 D-0 S-0
Freecells:  5C  JD
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC 3C 4C
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D AC 3S
: 5H 8C 8S 5D AD TS 6C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 4H
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 2D 5S JC AH
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move a card from stack 7 to the foundations

Foundations: H-A C-0 D-0 S-0
Freecells:  5C  JD
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC 3C 4C
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D AC 3S
: 5H 8C 8S 5D AD TS 6C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 4H
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 2D 5S JC
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move a card from stack 3 to freecell 3

Foundations: H-A C-0 D-0 S-0
Freecells:  5C  JD  3S
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC 3C 4C
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D AC
: 5H 8C 8S 5D AD TS 6C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 4H
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 2D 5S JC
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move a card from stack 3 to freecell 4

Foundations: H-A C-0 D-0 S-0
Freecells:  5C  JD  3S  AC
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC 3C 4C
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D
: 5H 8C 8S 5D AD TS 6C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 4H
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 2D 5S JC
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move a card from freecell 1 to stack 3

Foundations: H-A C-0 D-0 S-0
Freecells:      JD  3S  AC
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC 3C 4C
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D 5C
: 5H 8C 8S 5D AD TS 6C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 4H
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 2D 5S JC
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move a card from freecell 4 to the foundations

Foundations: H-A C-A D-0 S-0
Freecells:      JD  3S
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC 3C 4C
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D 5C
: 5H 8C 8S 5D AD TS 6C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 4H
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 2D 5S JC
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move a card from freecell 3 to stack 5

Foundations: H-A C-A D-0 S-0
Freecells:      JD
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC 3C 4C
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D 5C
: 5H 8C 8S 5D AD TS 6C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 4H 3S
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 2D 5S JC
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move a card from stack 2 to freecell 1

Foundations: H-A C-A D-0 S-0
Freecells:  4C  JD
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC 3C
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D 5C
: 5H 8C 8S 5D AD TS 6C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 4H 3S
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 2D 5S JC
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move a card from stack 2 to freecell 4

Foundations: H-A C-A D-0 S-0
Freecells:  4C  JD      3C
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D 5C
: 5H 8C 8S 5D AD TS 6C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 4H 3S
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 2D 5S JC
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move a card from freecell 2 to stack 2

Foundations: H-A C-A D-0 S-0
Freecells:  4C          3C
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D 5C
: 5H 8C 8S 5D AD TS 6C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 4H 3S
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 2D 5S JC
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move a card from stack 4 to freecell 3

Foundations: H-A C-A D-0 S-0
Freecells:  4C      6C  3C
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D 5C
: 5H 8C 8S 5D AD TS
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 4H 3S
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 2D 5S JC
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move a card from stack 4 to freecell 2

Foundations: H-A C-A D-0 S-0
Freecells:  4C  TS  6C  3C
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D 5C
: 5H 8C 8S 5D AD
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 4H 3S
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 2D 5S JC
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move a card from stack 4 to the foundations

Foundations: H-A C-A D-A S-0
Freecells:  4C  TS  6C  3C
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D 5C
: 5H 8C 8S 5D
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 4H 3S
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 2D 5S JC
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move a card from freecell 1 to stack 4

Foundations: H-A C-A D-A S-0
Freecells:      TS  6C  3C
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D 5C
: 5H 8C 8S 5D 4C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 4H 3S
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 2D 5S JC
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move a card from freecell 2 to stack 2

Foundations: H-A C-A D-A S-0
Freecells:          6C  3C
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D 5C
: 5H 8C 8S 5D 4C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 4H 3S
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 2D 5S JC
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move a card from stack 7 to freecell 1

Foundations: H-A C-A D-A S-0
Freecells:  JC      6C  3C
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D 5C
: 5H 8C 8S 5D 4C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 4H 3S
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 2D 5S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move a card from stack 7 to freecell 2

Foundations: H-A C-A D-A S-0
Freecells:  JC  5S  6C  3C
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D 5C
: 5H 8C 8S 5D 4C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 4H 3S
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 2D
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move a card from stack 7 to the foundations

Foundations: H-A C-A D-2 S-0
Freecells:  JC  5S  6C  3C
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D 5C
: 5H 8C 8S 5D 4C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 4H 3S
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
:
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move a card from freecell 2 to stack 7

Foundations: H-A C-A D-2 S-0
Freecells:  JC      6C  3C
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D 5C
: 5H 8C 8S 5D 4C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 4H 3S
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 5S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move 2 cards from stack 5 to stack 7

Foundations: H-A C-A D-2 S-0
Freecells:  JC      6C  3C
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D 5C
: 5H 8C 8S 5D 4C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move 2 cards from stack 4 to stack 5

Foundations: H-A C-A D-2 S-0
Freecells:  JC      6C  3C
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D 5C
: 5H 8C 8S
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 5D 4C
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move 1 cards from stack 4 to stack 8

Foundations: H-A C-A D-2 S-0
Freecells:  JC      6C  3C
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS
: 7D 7H 9S TH 6D 5C
: 5H 8C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 5D 4C
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move 2 cards from stack 3 to stack 6

Foundations: H-A C-A D-2 S-0
Freecells:  JC      6C  3C
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS
: 7D 7H 9S TH
: 5H 8C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 5D 4C
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C 6D 5C
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move a card from stack 1 to freecell 2

Foundations: H-A C-A D-2 S-0
Freecells:  JC  8H  6C  3C
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C 9D
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS
: 7D 7H 9S TH
: 5H 8C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 5D 4C
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C 6D 5C
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move 1 cards from stack 1 to stack 2

Foundations: H-A C-A D-2 S-0
Freecells:  JC  8H  6C  3C
: 8D 4D QH KS 2C
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 9S TH
: 5H 8C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 5D 4C
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C 6D 5C
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move a card from stack 1 to the foundations

Foundations: H-A C-2 D-2 S-0
Freecells:  JC  8H  6C  3C
: 8D 4D QH KS
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 9S TH
: 5H 8C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 5D 4C
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C 6D 5C
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move a card from freecell 4 to the foundations

Foundations: H-A C-3 D-2 S-0
Freecells:  JC  8H  6C
: 8D 4D QH KS
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 9S TH
: 5H 8C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 5D 4C
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C 6D 5C
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move a card from stack 5 to the foundations

Foundations: H-A C-4 D-2 S-0
Freecells:  JC  8H  6C
: 8D 4D QH KS
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 9S TH
: 5H 8C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 5D
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C 6D 5C
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move a card from stack 6 to the foundations

Foundations: H-A C-5 D-2 S-0
Freecells:  JC  8H  6C
: 8D 4D QH KS
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 9S TH
: 5H 8C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 5D
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C 6D
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move a card from freecell 3 to the foundations

Foundations: H-A C-6 D-2 S-0
Freecells:  JC  8H
: 8D 4D QH KS
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 9S TH
: 5H 8C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S 5D
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C 6D
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move a card from stack 5 to freecell 4

Foundations: H-A C-6 D-2 S-0
Freecells:  JC  8H      5D
: 8D 4D QH KS
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 9S TH
: 5H 8C
: 3H QD KH 9C 6S
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C 6D
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move a card from stack 5 to freecell 3

Foundations: H-A C-6 D-2 S-0
Freecells:  JC  8H  6S  5D
: 8D 4D QH KS
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 9S TH
: 5H 8C
: 3H QD KH 9C
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C 6D
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move a card from freecell 2 to stack 5

Foundations: H-A C-6 D-2 S-0
Freecells:  JC      6S  5D
: 8D 4D QH KS
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 9S TH
: 5H 8C
: 3H QD KH 9C 8H
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C 6D
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move a card from stack 1 to freecell 2

Foundations: H-A C-6 D-2 S-0
Freecells:  JC  KS  6S  5D
: 8D 4D QH
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 9S TH
: 5H 8C
: 3H QD KH 9C 8H
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C 6D
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move a card from freecell 1 to stack 1

Foundations: H-A C-6 D-2 S-0
Freecells:      KS  6S  5D
: 8D 4D QH JC
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 9S TH
: 5H 8C
: 3H QD KH 9C 8H
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C 6D
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move a card from stack 6 to freecell 1

Foundations: H-A C-6 D-2 S-0
Freecells:  6D  KS  6S  5D
: 8D 4D QH JC
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 9S TH
: 5H 8C
: 3H QD KH 9C 8H
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC 7C
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move a card from stack 6 to the foundations

Foundations: H-A C-7 D-2 S-0
Freecells:  6D  KS  6S  5D
: 8D 4D QH JC
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 9S TH
: 5H 8C
: 3H QD KH 9C 8H
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move a card from stack 4 to the foundations

Foundations: H-A C-8 D-2 S-0
Freecells:  6D  KS  6S  5D
: 8D 4D QH JC
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 9S TH
: 5H
: 3H QD KH 9C 8H
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move 1 cards from stack 3 to stack 1

Foundations: H-A C-8 D-2 S-0
Freecells:  6D  KS  6S  5D
: 8D 4D QH JC TH
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 9S
: 5H
: 3H QD KH 9C 8H
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move 1 cards from stack 3 to stack 1

Foundations: H-A C-8 D-2 S-0
Freecells:  6D  KS  6S  5D
: 8D 4D QH JC TH 9S
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H
: 5H
: 3H QD KH 9C 8H
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move a card from freecell 3 to stack 3

Foundations: H-A C-8 D-2 S-0
Freecells:  6D  KS      5D
: 8D 4D QH JC TH 9S
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 6S
: 5H
: 3H QD KH 9C 8H
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move a card from stack 5 to freecell 3

Foundations: H-A C-8 D-2 S-0
Freecells:  6D  KS  8H  5D
: 8D 4D QH JC TH 9S
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 6S
: 5H
: 3H QD KH 9C
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move a card from stack 5 to the foundations

Foundations: H-A C-9 D-2 S-0
Freecells:  6D  KS  8H  5D
: 8D 4D QH JC TH 9S
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 6S
: 5H
: 3H QD KH
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move a card from freecell 3 to stack 1

Foundations: H-A C-9 D-2 S-0
Freecells:  6D  KS      5D
: 8D 4D QH JC TH 9S 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 6S
: 5H
: 3H QD KH
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move 1 cards from stack 4 to stack 3

Foundations: H-A C-9 D-2 S-0
Freecells:  6D  KS      5D
: 8D 4D QH JC TH 9S 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 6S 5H
:
: 3H QD KH
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move a card from freecell 1 to stack 4

Foundations: H-A C-9 D-2 S-0
Freecells:      KS      5D
: 8D 4D QH JC TH 9S 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 6S 5H
: 6D
: 3H QD KH
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC
: 5S 4H 3S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move 3 cards from stack 7 to stack 4

Foundations: H-A C-9 D-2 S-0
Freecells:      KS      5D
: 8D 4D QH JC TH 9S 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 6S 5H
: 6D 5S 4H 3S
: 3H QD KH
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC
:
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move a card from freecell 4 to stack 7

Foundations: H-A C-9 D-2 S-0
Freecells:      KS
: 8D 4D QH JC TH 9S 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 6S 5H
: 6D 5S 4H 3S
: 3H QD KH
: 6H 2H JS 4S KC
: 5D
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move a card from stack 6 to freecell 3

Foundations: H-A C-9 D-2 S-0
Freecells:      KS  KC
: 8D 4D QH JC TH 9S 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 6S 5H
: 6D 5S 4H 3S
: 3H QD KH
: 6H 2H JS 4S
: 5D
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move 1 cards from stack 6 to stack 7

Foundations: H-A C-9 D-2 S-0
Freecells:      KS  KC
: 8D 4D QH JC TH 9S 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 6S 5H
: 6D 5S 4H 3S
: 3H QD KH
: 6H 2H JS
: 5D 4S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H 8S


====================

Move a card from stack 8 to freecell 1

Foundations: H-A C-9 D-2 S-0
Freecells:  8S  KS  KC
: 8D 4D QH JC TH 9S 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 6S 5H
: 6D 5S 4H 3S
: 3H QD KH
: 6H 2H JS
: 5D 4S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D 9H


====================

Move a card from stack 8 to freecell 4

Foundations: H-A C-9 D-2 S-0
Freecells:  8S  KS  KC  9H
: 8D 4D QH JC TH 9S 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 6S 5H
: 6D 5S 4H 3S
: 3H QD KH
: 6H 2H JS
: 5D 4S
: 7S TD TC JH 3D


====================

Move a card from stack 8 to the foundations

Foundations: H-A C-9 D-3 S-0
Freecells:  8S  KS  KC  9H
: 8D 4D QH JC TH 9S 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D
: 7D 7H 6S 5H
: 6D 5S 4H 3S
: 3H QD KH
: 6H 2H JS
: 5D 4S
: 7S TD TC JH


====================

Move a card from freecell 1 to stack 2

Foundations: H-A C-9 D-3 S-0
Freecells:      KS  KC  9H
: 8D 4D QH JC TH 9S 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D 8S
: 7D 7H 6S 5H
: 6D 5S 4H 3S
: 3H QD KH
: 6H 2H JS
: 5D 4S
: 7S TD TC JH


====================

Move a card from stack 8 to freecell 1

Foundations: H-A C-9 D-3 S-0
Freecells:  JH  KS  KC  9H
: 8D 4D QH JC TH 9S 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D 8S
: 7D 7H 6S 5H
: 6D 5S 4H 3S
: 3H QD KH
: 6H 2H JS
: 5D 4S
: 7S TD TC


====================

Move a card from freecell 4 to stack 8

Foundations: H-A C-9 D-3 S-0
Freecells:  JH  KS  KC
: 8D 4D QH JC TH 9S 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D 8S
: 7D 7H 6S 5H
: 6D 5S 4H 3S
: 3H QD KH
: 6H 2H JS
: 5D 4S
: 7S TD TC 9H


====================

Move a card from stack 8 to freecell 4

Foundations: H-A C-9 D-3 S-0
Freecells:  JH  KS  KC  9H
: 8D 4D QH JC TH 9S 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D 8S
: 7D 7H 6S 5H
: 6D 5S 4H 3S
: 3H QD KH
: 6H 2H JS
: 5D 4S
: 7S TD TC


====================

Move a card from stack 8 to the foundations

Foundations: H-A C-T D-3 S-0
Freecells:  JH  KS  KC  9H
: 8D 4D QH JC TH 9S 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D 8S
: 7D 7H 6S 5H
: 6D 5S 4H 3S
: 3H QD KH
: 6H 2H JS
: 5D 4S
: 7S TD


====================

Move 1 cards from stack 8 to stack 6

Foundations: H-A C-T D-3 S-0
Freecells:  JH  KS  KC  9H
: 8D 4D QH JC TH 9S 8H
: QS AS 2S KD QC JD TS 9D 8S
: 7D 7H 6S 5H
: 6D 5S 4H 3S
: 3H QD KH
: 6H 2H JS TD
: 5D 4S
: 7S
```

Comment: You forgot two colons in the `[1] https//` part. Should be `[1]: https://`

Comment: Thanks, accidentally broke it while messing with the quoted bit from the solver.